# getting sum values based on two where conditions in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table as follows:

[image]

Highlighted in red color is base PRDS (IM) which will be used for different PCK like:

```
ABC & XYZ
DEF & XYZ
```

What I want is as follows:

[image]

And

[image]

I tried two where conditions but its not working. Kindly help me out to solve this.

following is my code:

```php
$sql="SELECT bom. OUTPRDSRL,
             bom. BOPPRDCD,
             bom. OUTPRDNAME,
             bom. PRDSTGCD,
             SUM(bom. REQQTY) AS RTOTAL,
             SUM(bom. TOTALVALUE) AS RRTOTAL,
             SUM(bom.TOTALVALUE * b_master.calculation) / 100 +
             SUM(bom.TOTALVALUE) AS TOTAL,
             b_master. PRDSTGCD,
             b_master. calculation
        FROM bom
       INNER JOIN b_master
          ON bom. PRDSTGCD = b_master. PRDSTGCD
       WHERE BOPPRDCD = '$BOPPRDCD'
         AND OUTPRDCD = '$OUTPRDCD'
       GROUP BY OUTPRDNAME
       ORDER BY PRDSTGDES";
```

Comment: _"I tried two where conditions"_ Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74470785/edit) to show us what you tried.

Comment: As per question guidelines, please do not post images

Comment: Hint : `WITH ROLLUP`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste your data as formatted text here instead.

Comment: Can I attached excel file to given clear examples.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how your query relates to the tables you are showing. So, here is my answer refering to the tables.

You have a table and want to show all its rows (or all IM rows plus all rows for one name). In these rows you also want to show sums. In order to do that you need `SUM OVER`.

### IM and one name only:

```
select
  t.*,
  sum(qty) over (partition by prds, name) as subtotal,
  sum(qty) over () as total
from mytable t
where prds = 'IM' or (prds = 'PCK' and name = 'ABC')
order by (prds = 'IM') desc, stg;
```

### All rows:

```
select
  t.*,
  sum(qty) over (partition by prds, name) as subtotal,
  sum(case when prds = 'IM' then qty end) over () +
  sum(case when prds <> 'IM' then qty end) over (partition by name)
    as total
from mytable t
where prds = 'IM' or (prds = 'PCK' and name = 'ABC')
order by (prds = 'IM') desc, stg;
```

This will show the sums in every row. Use your GUI layer (your app or Website) to only display the sums where you want them. The same can be done in SQL using `LEAD`, but it is better to deal with layout things in your GUI layer.

Comment: Thanks! can you please exlain t.* and mytable t, also will "over" work in sql or php mysql kindly expedite.

Comment: `mytable` is the table in question. Replace it with your table name. `t` is an alias for it. `t.*` is all columns from the table. `OVER` is standard SQL. MySQL has featured this for some years now, since version 8.0.

Comment: okay, Will you please allow me to share my excel file to make it more elaborate.